# validation in number input and want to get same output as input without in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rubygems, number-formatting

when i input 0.0001.
i get the output as 0.0001.
when i input 0.00001 or more 0 before 1.
then i gote 1.0e-5 or value more than 5.

this is my index on admin panel.

```
 index do
    selectable_column
    column :id
    column :transaction_type
    column "Single Coin Worth($)", :single_coin_worth
    
    # actions defaults: true #for all actions like(edit, show and delete)
    actions defaults: false do |coin_setting|
      item "Show", admin_setting_path(coin_setting), class: "member_link"
      item "Edit", edit_admin_setting_path(coin_setting), class: "member_link"
    end
  end
```

i also want to restrict e notation in input field.

this is my fourm for admin panel

```
form do |f| 
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors[:base]
    f.inputs do
      f.input :single_coin_worth, {required: true, min: 0, max: 100000}
      f.input :transaction_type, as: :select, collection: ['purchase', 'withdrawl']
      f.actions
    end
  end
```

i have these validations in model

```
validates :single_coin_worth, presence: true

validates :single_coin_worth, numericality: {:less_than_or_equal_to => 1}

validates :single_coin_worth, numericality: {:greater_than => 0}

validates :transaction_type, presence: true, inclusion: {in: ['purchase', 'withdrawl']}
```

I want output number is same as input.
i also want to restrict all things in input field ecxept decimal point and digits.

Comment: what are these `form do...` and `index do...` methods? do they relate to some particular gem? What file are they in? They don't look like any ruby/rails methods that I'm familiar with!

Comment: these are admin panel methods to get the list of created data. and form do used to create data.

Answer (score 0):

That's the default behavior of a `Number` in rails (defined by it's `to_s`).

If in your views, you want to show it in the way that you just described above, here are the two things (that I can think of) that you can do.

1. Use [NumberHelper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html): `number_with_precision` in your views.
2. Mark the attribute as a float in your model

   ```rb
   class YourModel  
     attribute :single_coin_worth, :float
   ```

There's another way, that's monkey patching the `Number#to_s` method but I'd advise you not to do that, emphasis on NOT. That'd be changing a core library behavior which is never a good thing and can create some nasty bugs in the future.

All the best.